# xunit tests don't save output to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I have the following preconditions:

1. Visual Studio 2015 Community, `dnx version 1.0.0-beta5`
2. ASP.NET vNext project
3. ASP.NET vNext project with unit-tests (further: Unit-test project)
4. `project.json` in Unit-test project

   ```
   "frameworks": {
   "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      "xunit": "2.1.0-beta3-*",
      "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta3-*",
      "xunit.abstractions": "2.0.0",
      "Moq": "4.2.1507.118",
       }
    }
   },
   "commands": {
   "test": "xunit.runner.dnx -xml TestResults.xml"
   },
   ```

When I run tests within Visual Studio, a new file TestResults.xml is created, but it is empty except for :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assemblies>
  <assembly />
</assemblies>
```

When I run the command `dnx . test -xml TestResults.xml` from cmd, I get the XML file with results. What should I do to obtain the same result if run tests from Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you tried just running dnx test? It will pick up the arguments in the test command.

Comment: @BrianVallelunga, yes, I wrote about it just after tag </assemblies>. The question is about running tests from Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a reason for using -beta5 instead of the RC recently released?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your commands to this:

```
{
    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    }
}
```

And running your command line like this: `dnx test -xml TestResults.xml` ? As far as I see it, there's no reason why the command line parameters wouldn't be forwarded to the runner.

Comment: This does work, however, the poster is looking to emulate this result when running the tests via Visual Studio's Test Explorer.

Comment: I'll keep this answer up for posterity but I don't think it's bringing anything more to this conversation.